# Why random generator only generates zero

Tags: c

```
main()
{
     int i;
     srand((int)time(NULL));
     for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     printf("%f\n", randomInRange(0, 100));   // %f instead of %d
}

int randomInRange(int lo, int hi)
{

     double d = (double)rand() / ((double)RAND_MAX + 1);
     int k = (int)(d * (hi - lo + 1));
     return k+lo;
}
```

when using %d to print the value, it works well
but if I choose %f instead of %d, it generates 0 only
why ?

Comment: A `float` is not an `int` is not a `float`...

Comment: Because `printf` doesn't do  conversions? Try `printf("%f\n", (float)randomInRange(0, 100));`

Comment: I suggest you use `-Wformat` if it is supported by your compiler.

Comment: To numbers in the range `[M, N]` you should use `M + rand() / (RAND_MAX / (N - M + 1) + 1)`, read: [How can I get random integers in a certain range?](http://c-faq.com/lib/randrange.html)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is unlikely to help other visitors to Stack Overflow in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Section 7.21.6.1p9 of n1570.pdf (the C standard) says, in relation to printf:

> ... If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding
>   conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

Section 7.21.6.1p8 states the correct type for the `%f` format specifier:

> **f,F** A `double` argument representing a floating-point number is
>   converted to decimal notation in the style [−]ddd.ddd, where the
>   number of digits after the decimal-point character is equal to the
>   precision specification.

`randomInRange` returns an int. An int is clearly not a double, thus the behaviour is undefined. A chicken may run and jump around despite it's head being missing... That chicken might or might not cause someone to fall over and break their neck. Avoid headless chickens, and undefined behaviour.

Please consult the manual and try to find answers yourself before asking questions in the future. By doing so, you'll be helping to reduce the redundancy of this information on the internet.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that small integers (< 2^23) interpreted as floats are *really* small.

```
s eeeeeee emmmmmmm mmmmmmmm mmmmmmmm  == sign * 1.mmmmmm * 2^(eeeee - 128)
0 0000000 00000000 00000000 11111111  == 255 as integer
```

This 32-bit integer split to bits and interpreted as float is about 255 * 2^-128, or about 3.57e-43, which is correctly shown as 0.0.

You can also try to print it as "%e", which shows a scientific representation, or "%g" which shows "the smallest accurate" representation.

Comment: so you mean the result is not "undefined" as @modifiable lvalue said ? It's just too small to be interpreted... right?

Comment: Even undefined behaviour _is_ typically something. Changing the specifier to "%g" outputs 6.95316e-310, which is actually of type double, but I think the point is proven.

Answer (score 0):

I know a very easy and good way to randomize a number in c

```
 #include<stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

srand(time(NULL));

int  r = rand()%100;
```

just write this in c and the random number will be put in "r"